# ExtJS & ASP.NET MVC 4 on multipage application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, extjs, web-applications, architecture, multipage

-->Questions are at the end of the post.

I want to use ExtJs on a multipage application with ASP.NET MVC. I know one of the MVC purposes is to build clean and fast HTML pages, but let's just say I have to use ExtJs.

Given the fact that ExtJs is mainly a single page app oriented framework, *I had to find a way to make it work on multipage apps.*

**So, my layout page looks like this:**

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET MVC Application</title>
        <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        @*Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")*@

        @Styles.Render("~/Resources/css/app.css")
        @Styles.Render("~/ExtJs/ext-theme-neptune-all-debug_01.css")
        @Styles.Render("~/ExtJs/ext-theme-neptune-all-debug_02.css")
        @Scripts.Render("~/ExtJs/ext-all-debug.js")
        @Scripts.Render("~/App/app.js")
        @RenderSection("actionscripts", required: false)

    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="body">
            <section class="">
                @RenderBody()
            </section>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**App.js is my app starter and simplified looks like this:**

```
APP = {}
BuildActionHTML = null;
Ext.application({
    name: 'MyApp',
    launch: function () {
        APP = this;
        APP.VIEWPORT = Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
            layout: 'border',
            cls: 'spViewport',
            maxWidth: 1280,
            minWidth:960,
            items: [{
                region: 'center',
                xtype: 'panel',
                title: 'Main content',
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'label',
                    html: '<div id = "mainAppContainer"></div>',
                    listeners: {
                        afterrender: function (label, eOpts) {
                            BuildActionHTML && typeof BuildActionHTML == 'function' && BuildActionHTML();
                        }
                    }
                }]
            }]
        });

    }
});
```

**Now, my Index view in Home controller (and any other view) looks like this:**

```
@section actionscripts
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function BuildActionHTML() {
            Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel', {
                title: 'My panel',
                width: '100%',
                renderTo: 'mainAppContainer',
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    fieldLabel: 'Text field'
                }]
            })
        }
    </script>
}
```

So my viewport contains a panel with a label which has a label in it. After rendering the label with that `<div id = "mainAppContainer"></div>` I know for sure I can start rendering my view in it, by calling `BuildActionHTML()`

---

***1.*** My question is how bad is this approach, because I know for sure it is not elegant. What "problems" will I probably get into and what are the advantages/disadvantages.

***2.*** Also, how can I customize ext-all.js to use only the classes and components I am using in application, to reduce its size. I don't think I can to this with sencha cmd due to my app architecture (or the lack of it).

Thank you.